# Using VFP Reports within a C# .Net Web Application

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

Thank you in advance. I am self taught, so please forgive my lack of 'tech speak'.

I am in the process of converting my VFP application to a C# .Net web application. The VFP application has been in use by various clients for almost 20 years and has 280 report forms printable from the interface. I would like to reuse these reports in my new web application.  I have built a new VFP app that includes all the reports, dlls, etc and includes procedures with the various parameters for several reports which works fine when run from the shared folder, however when code in C# is executed, an error is thrown.

```
String _path = Convert.ToString(Session["ReportPath"]);
String nwstr = Convert.ToString(Session["SOOrderID"]);
String generalchk = Convert.ToInt16(this.GeneralCheck.Checked).ToString();
String newchk = Convert.ToInt16(this.NewCheck.Checked).ToString();
String moneychk = Convert.ToInt16(this.ExcludeCheck.Checked).ToString();
String shipkey = this.ShipList.SelectedValue;
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "run_reports.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @_path;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "DO single_ordr_prnt WITH " + "'" + @nwstr + "', '" 
+ @generalchk + "', '" + @newchk + "', '" + @moneychk + "', '" +        @shipkey   + "'";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.Start();
```

I get an error when Fox fires telling me that there is no parameter 
statement.  I have double checked the argument string both with and without 
single quotes and always get the same error. I have SET PROCEDURES TO 'procedures.prg' and the procedures all reside there. 'Single_ordr_prnt' is the procedure name and 'Run_Reports' is the exe name.

Any help will be appreciated.  I have worked on this for two days and have run out of ideas.

JLB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call that is being executed is the Run_Reports, not the function WITHIN that executable, so the parameters list is being passed to Run_Reports and not the "single_ordr_prnt".

To TRY a work-around, you might want to adjust how it is being called, but you are getting values from a web-page and that is / can be dangerous most commonly within any SQL engine... VFP can still be hacked by SQL-injection, but if someone is not savvy with VFP, VFP will just throw-up and fail.

You could try by building your string as an "ExecScript()" call in VFP, but you are still limited to the parameter length that a shell executed call will offer.  Just to TEST the theory, and from within the VFP environment, you can try something like this...

do Run_Reports with [ExecScript( "Do single_ordr_prnt with 'blah', 'blah', etc" )]

and the first line in your "Run_Reports" program should be a parameter, and test to make sure it looks like you would expect, and only be a single parameter.  This would help in case someone puts in a web-based string any extra quotes that would falsely offset your expected strings and fail in VFP.

```
PARAMETERS pcParmFromWebSite, pcBadParm1, pcBadParm2, pcBadParm3

IF PCOUNT() > 1
   */ Error out
   return
endif 

if PCOUNT() = 1 AND atc( "ExecScript", pcParmFromWebSite ) = 1
   */ The "&" does macro substitution and will in-fact ISSUE the
   */ ExecScript with the parameters is has inclusive with it.
   &pcParmFromWebSite
   return whatever...
endif
```

So, although this is an option (again, pre-test WITHIN VFP), I would strongly suggest doing what you can to port the stuff over directly to web pages and pull the data down directly to the web via VFPOleDB connection directly to your database with C#.  The reports you would get from VFP can't be directly pushed to the web (to the best my experience and using VFP since '93).

FEEDBACK FROM COMMENT...

I too have used frx2any, but what you may opt to do is generate a .PDF and return that as a stream feed.  I don't know the performance requirements for the reports and/or lag time in returning.

Another option you may consider is creating a COM/OlePublic server class exposing the methods in your executable.  That is too much to actually cover here in this forum... and there are even other alternatives with VFP and the web.

Comment: Thank  you for your input.  I will try your suggestion.  Thing is if I execute the 'DO' from within VFP and execute from my web app, my fox window shows from within the web application so it is connecting, but I cannot control which procedure fires nor control the parameters. Also,  I have used frx2any for years, allowing the user to save the output of any report to anything (pdf, xml, to printer, etc). This 3rd party software may also be interfering.  What reporting app do you recommend for a web application?

Comment: @JLB, see feedback in answer.

Comment: I got this routine to work perfectly even with my frx2any application by using the wait window function in my fox app to build a string from the LParameters list.  Thanks for the LParameters tip.

Comment: I got this routine to work perfectly even with my frx2any application by using the wait window function in my fox app to build a string from the LParameters list.  Thanks for the LParameters tip.

Comment: I got this routine to work perfectly even with my frx2any application by using the wait window function in my fox app to build a string from the LParameters list.  Thanks for the LParameters tip.

Comment: @JLB, so.. if it worked, mark as solved so others too know what worked for your scenario.

Comment: Upon review of the C# code, the following should be changed"

Comment: Upon review of the C# code, the following statements should be changed as any spaces in a StartInfo.Argument statement translates to an additional parameter:
    String parms = "'" + nwstr + "','" + generalchk + "','" + newchk + "','" + moneychk + "','" + shipkey + "'";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "single_ordr_prnt " + parms; 
I only really needed 2 parameters.